# Where should I put the timeout to auto refresh the page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to auto-refresh the page so I can retrieve the latest data from a database.

I expect it will be show the latest data without pressing anything but it still doesn't show up when I try to input new data

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  load_data();

  function load_data(query) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "php/checkinhelper.php",
      method: "post",
      data: {
        query: query
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#result').html(data);
      }
    });
    window.setTimeout(100);
  }

  $('#search_text').change(function() {
    var search = $(this).val();
    if (search != '') {
      load_data(search);
    } else {
      window.setTimeout(100);
      load_data();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Firstly your `setTimeout()` calls need to have some logic in them to be executed when the timeout expires. See the correct syntax in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). That being said, I don't see why you need a timeout here? Are you trying to debounce the `change` event?

Comment: call `load_data()` in `setTimeout`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this one:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 load_data();

     function load_data(query) {
$.ajax({
  url: "php/checkinhelper.php",
  method: "post",
  data: {
    query: query
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);
  }
});

}

setTimeout(function(){ load_data() }, 100);

$('#search_text').change(function() {
var search = $(this).val();
if (search != '') {
  load_data(search);
} else {
  window.setTimeout(100);
  load_data();
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        var elem = $('#search_text');

         setTimeout(() =>  elem.trigger('change'), 100);

          function load_data(query) {
            $.ajax({
              url: "php/checkinhelper.php",
              method: "post",
              data: {
                query: query
              },
              success: (data) => {
                  $('#result').html(data);
                  setTimeout(() =>  elem.trigger('change'), 100);
              }
            });
          }

          elem.change(function() {
            var search = $(this).val();
            if (search != '') {
              load_data(search);
            } 
          });
        });
```